# sql query to fetch top 3 salaries

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

```
  emp_name |salary
  ---------------
  A        |12568
  B        |3000
  C        |7852
  D        |2568
  E        |9852
  F        |1598
  G        |8569
```

I want a sql query to fetch the lowest 3 salaried employees

Comment: What is your sql server? Some uses top, some uses limit.

Comment: What if there are two employees with the same, third salary?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle 12c or later you can make your query simpler with `fetch`. Instead of writing inner queries like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES EMP ORDER BY EMP.SALARY ASC
  )
WHERE ROWNNUM <= 3
```

You can combine them into a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM employees emp ORDER BY emp.salary ASC
FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY;
```

More Information on the syntax and construct is available here. 
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_offset_fet_first_rows_only.htm

Comment: The second one is also the ANSI SQL answer!

Comment: Yes, but the oracle version should still be 12c or higher right?

Comment: I don't know the details, just wanted to point out the ANSI SQL answer. (More recent Oracle versions is as detailed as I know...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use top 3 to get three record after ordering them in descending or ascending order. I have SQL server syntax but you can have idea from this for you target DBMS.

For top three max salaries

```
Select top 3 emp_name, salary
order by salary desc
```

For top three minimum salaries

```
Select top 3 emp_name, salary
order by salary asc
```

Answer (score 0):

ORACLE:

```
SELECT emp_name
  FROM (  SELECT *
            FROM employees e
        ORDER BY e.salary ASC)
 WHERE ROWNUM < 4
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

USE `ASC` AND `LIMIT`

```
Select  emp_name, salary FROM TABLE_NAME
order by salary ASC LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select emp_name, salary
from (
  select emp_name, salary,
         dense_rank() over (order by salary) as rnk
  from employees
) t
where rnk <= 3;
```

This will also deal with employees that have the same salary. So the result might be more then three rows if more then one of the employees with the lowest salary have the same salary.

Comment: Interesting .. all super-reputation users and professional programmers in the database field have similar avatars :-) http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff